# Iteratively print matlab struct

Tags: matlab, matlab-struct

I have a matlab struct with the following structure

```
Tree:
feature : numerical value (= 1)
tru: numerical value (= 2)
gain: numerical value (= 3)
left: struct with left node
right: struct with right node
```

How do I print this out in the form of a tree? For example I want to print out for the root node:

```
node 1 feature 1, tru 2, gain 3
```

Nodes 2 and 3 contain data from the `left` and `right` structs respectively, with the same structure as root node.

I want to recursively print the entire tree using the same format as I describe above for node 1.

I can print my node 1 by

```
tree.feature

tree.tru

tree.gain
```

I cant get how to print its children recursively for all nodes.

Comment: i want to recursive print the entire tree using the same format

Comment: What have you *tried*? For example, have you got code to at least print your example output for node 1? This could be built upon to be done recursively...

Comment: I posted some code i think will work for node 1 but how do i do this for all nodes

Comment: What is the stop condition? Will there be a point where there is no `tree.left`?

Comment: yes it will stop when the node features , tru and gain is -1

Comment: There are a limited number of nodes in my tree and i want to know how to print it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to have a simple recursive function like this

```
function printinfo(node)

% Display the details from this node
disp(['Feature: ', num2str(node.feature), ...
    '\nTru: ', num2str(node.tru), ...
    '\nGain: ', num2str(node.gain)]);

% If any of feature, tru or gain aren't equal to -1, go into left and right
if node.feature ~= -1 || node.tru ~= -1 || node.gain ~= -1
    printinfo(node.left)
    printinfo(node.right)
end

end
```

Initially calling it using

```
printinfo(tree)
```

Then each node calls the function of its respective `right` and `left` nodes, unless the stop condition you described in the comments is reached:

> *It will stop when the node features, tru and gain is -1*